# bootstrap multi error in single alert

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I looked around a bit, but I have not found anything.

I have this code, and I can not create a single alert for all errors that come out (as if it were a bulleted list)

```
if(isset($error)){
                foreach ($error as $error)
                {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">';
                    echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the alert out of the loop

```
if(isset($error)){
    echo '<ul class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">';
    foreach ($error as $error)
    {
        echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
<ul>
<?php
if(isset($error)){
 foreach ($error as $err)
       {
          echo '<li>'.$err.'</li>';
          }
   }
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This will show an empty alert without text when no error occured.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this .. hope it will work for you

```
 if(isset($error)){
      $errAlert = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">';
                foreach ($error as $err) {
                    $errAlert .= '<p>'.$err.'</p>';
                }
       $errAlert .= '</div>';
      echo $errAlert; // print this variable where you want
   }
```

Comment: `foreach ($a as $a)` is unusual, but it works. No need to change it.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider i haven't noticed that before.